# C++ template match type without duplicate definition

Tags: c++, types, metaprogramming

I'm creating a template wrapper around std::function. To match void-returning functions, I have the std::monostate as my Unit type. I've been trying to create two variadic templates for my function wrapper type, one

```
template<Unit, Args...>
```

and one

```
template<T, Args...> where T != Unit.
```

This is the closest I've gotten by using `enable_if`.

```
#include <functional>
#include <variant>

namespace func {
    // Declare unit type
    typedef std::monostate Unit;

    // Empty type, maybe use this instead of monostate
    template<typename ... ts>
    struct Term {};

    // Variables
    template<typename T>
    struct Term<T>
    {
        T val;
        // Constructor
        Term(T in): val(in) {}

        // Call op just returns the value
        T operator() () const {
            return this->val;
        }
    };

    // Functions that return void
    template <typename T,
                typename ... Args,
                typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, Unit>::value>>
    struct Term<Args...>
    {
        // Void returning function
        const std::function<void(Args...)> body;

        // Void returning constructor
        Term(std::function<void(Args...)> func): body(func) {}

        // Void function Caller
        void operator() (const Args&& ...a) const {
            this->body(std::forward<Args>(a)...);
        }
    };

    // Functions that return T
    template <typename T,
                typename ... Args,
                typename = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<T, Unit>::value>>
    struct Term<T, Args...>
    {
        // T returning function
        const std::function<T(Args...)> body;

        // T returning constructor
        Term(std::function<T(Args...)> func): body(func) {}

        // T returning function Caller
        T operator() (const Args&& ...a) const {
            return this->body(std::forward<Args>(a)...);
        }
    };

}
```

However I'm getting errors about non-deducible parameter T in the first case. However, I already know that the parameter is gonna be of type `Unit` by my `enable_if` template parameter. How can I make the compiler accept both definitions?

**Error**:

```
$ clang++ -std=c++17 terms.hpp -pedantic
terms.hpp:29:18: error: default template argument in a class template partial specialization
                                typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, Unit>::value>>
                                           ^
terms.hpp:30:9: error: class template partial specialization contains template parameters that cannot be deduced; this partial specialization will never be used [-Wunusable-partial-specialization]
        struct Term<Args...>
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
terms.hpp:27:21: note: non-deducible template parameter 'T'
        template <typename T,
                           ^
terms.hpp:29:7: note: non-deducible template parameter (anonymous)
                                typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, Unit>::value>>
                                ^
terms.hpp:47:18: error: default template argument in a class template partial specialization
                                typename = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<T, Unit>::value>>
                                           ^
terms.hpp:48:9: error: class template partial specialization contains a template parameter that cannot be deduced; this partial specialization will never be used [-Wunusable-partial-specialization]
        struct Term<T, Args...>
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
terms.hpp:47:7: note: non-deducible template parameter (anonymous)
                                typename = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<T, Unit>::value>>
                                ^
4 errors generated.
```

EDIT: Should be used like this

```
auto c = Term<int>(42);
auto fun = Term<int, int, int>([](int a, int b) { return a + b; });

std::cout << c() << std::endl;
std::cout << fun(3,4) << std::endl;
```

Comment: I believe you should put the anonymous `enable_if` parameter after `Args`, not before.

Comment: @DanielH cool, thanks I edited to put the Args before the anonymous template parameter. Still getting the same error though, so it probably hasn't come to that yet.

Comment: How are you planning to instantiate this template?

Comment: VC++ claims that [default template arguments not allowed on a partial specialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c2756)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you currently have with your template specializations, is that `struct Term<Args...>` and `struct Term<T, Args...>` are not mutually exclusive and can match the same things.  Therefore I propose that you unify those two cases into one and SFINAE on the overloaded call operator.

This approach certainly has some limitations, but those are merely inherited from your original approach.  For example it is not possible to wrap a function which takes no arguments but returns a value (that is ambiguous with a scalar).

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>

namespace func {
    // Declare unit type
    typedef std::monostate Unit;

    // Empty type, maybe use this instead of monostate
    template<typename...>
    struct Term;

    // Variables
    template<typename T>
    struct Term<T>
    {
        T val;
        // Constructor
        Term(T in): val(in) {}

        // Call op just returns the value
        T operator() () const {
            return this->val;
        }
    };

    // Functions that return void
    template <typename T, typename ... Args>
    struct Term<T, Args...>
    {
        using R = typename std::conditional<std::is_same<T, Unit>::value,void,T>::type;
        // Void returning function
        const std::function<R(Args...)> body;

        // Void returning constructor
        Term(std::function<R(Args...)> func): body(func) {}

        // Void function Caller
        template <typename U = R>
        typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<U, Unit>::value,void>::type
        operator() (Args&& ...a) const {
            this->body(std::forward<Args>(a)...);
        }

        // T returning function Caller
        template <typename U = R>
        typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<U, Unit>::value,T>::type
        operator() (Args&& ...a) const {
            return this->body(std::forward<Args>(a)...);
        }

    };
}

int main() {
    auto c = func::Term<int>(42);
    auto fun = func::Term<int, int, int>([](int a, int b) { return a + b; });

    std::cout << c() << std::endl;
    std::cout << fun(3,4) << std::endl;
}
```

[Live example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/qJTtxbYgnGUznrC3)

Comment: That's awesome, I didn't know about std::conditional and I didn't know you could nest templates like this, to get around "default template arguments not allowed on a partial specialization" as was mentioned. Finally for "it is not possible to wrap a function which takes no arguments but returns a value" I can just declare those as variables, for example what I do for `c()` in `main`. Thanks again!

Comment: What if I wanted to also translate variadic `Args...` to void as well, like you did for `R`?

Comment: @rausted Why would you want to translate `Args...` to `void`?  That is not even possible, i.e. function signatures like e.g. `int(int,void,double)` are not valid C++.  The only valid case is `int(void)` where `void` is the only parameter and that is covered by the constant case, as you reasoned in your earlier comment.